# $G(x)\sqrt{A(x)}\geq \lambda \, \, \, \, \, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ e.g $2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\geq-1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

I realized I do not know how to solve a particular type of inequalities.

I needed to solve:

$$2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\geq-1$$
Usually with the irrational inequalities where the variable is just below the root and in the other member of the equation I set the following systems:
$$\sqrt{A(x)}\geq B(x)$$
$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
A(x)\geq 0\\ 
B(x)\geq 0\\ 
A(x)^{2}\geq B(x)^{2}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$\cup$$

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
A(x)\geq 0\\ 
B(x)\leq  0\\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

But in this case we do not have the variable in the second term and being an inequality I remember I can not to divide by a variable. I did not find on my book a clear analysis of these cases.

I am interested in the following cases:
 $$G(x)\sqrt{A(x)}\geq \lambda \, \, \, \, \, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$G(x)\sqrt{A(x)}\geq B(x)$$

Thank you a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for the particular inequality**

First of all

$$2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\ge 1\implies x>0, 1-x^2>0.$$ So, squaring we have

$$4x^2(1-x^2)\ge 1,$$ or

$$(2x^2-1)^2=4x^4-4x^2+1\le 0.$$ The only solution is $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ (remember, $x>0.$)